# Can i hide the field's column from Sale order line Based on sale order value In Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

If I tick on boolean field named 'Visible Cost', the labour cost(column) should be hide from sale order line.

Please find dropbox video link.

**https://www.dropbox.com/s/iya26jwy4awfl2f/hide%20field%20in%20sale%20order%20line.ogv?dl=0**

Thanks a lot in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a related field in the sale.order.line class reflecting the value of the sale.order attribute in each line:

```
 visible_cost = fields.Boolean(related='order_id.visible_cost')
```

Then extend the corresponding view and add an attrs attribute to the labour cost field in the sale order line. Note that you have to include the field in the view first (even invisible) to be able to use it in the attrs expression:

```
 <field name="visible_cost" invisible="1"/>
 <field name="..labour cost field name..." attrs="{'invisible':visible_cost}"/>
```

Comment: With this way, its not working.
visible_cost is the field of "sale.order" object.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I have edited the response to include how to make the saleorder-field available in the saleorderline objects.